# NSTimer continue during sleep mode

Tags: nstimer, sleep

I have a timer app which uses a NSTimer to track minutes. How can I keep the timer going, even when the device is put into sleep mode? Thanks!

Comment: You need to update your question with information about why you think you need the timer to keep going when the device is asleep. Most likely there is a better solution but it depends on what you need this for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Adjust After Wake Notification

Scheduled NSTimer instances will halt during sleep. Your application needs to respond to the NSWorkspace's wake notification and adjust its timers.

If you do not respond to wake notifications, your timers will resume but without accounting for the time spent asleep.

See Apple's technical note [QA1340 Registering and unregistering for sleep and wake notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1340/_index.html) for getting the appropriate notifications.

### Example

Consider this situation:

- Create a timer to trigger in 5 minutes
- Wait 1 minute
- Put the computer to sleep for *an hour*
- Wake the computer
- The timer resumes upon waking
- The timer triggers 4 minutes after waking

From the timer's perspective, five minutes has passed by. Note the language used by [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html), it uses relative durations rather than absolute times, `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:`.

Comment: What happens if I don't respond to wake notifications, as I am doing now?

Comment: Your timer will resume but not account for the time spent asleep.

Comment: Could I use something like NSDate to track and add the time spent asleep?

Comment: Yes, NSDate is the recommended way to get the current date and time. You will need to reschedule your timer after wake.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this class, which handles sleep/wake for you with the "Hourglass" behavior: https://github.com/jmah/MyLilTimer

Answer (score 1):

You can use wall time. Specifically, I recommend you to check out `DispatchSourceTimer.schedule(wallDeadline:)` or `DispatchQueue.asyncAfter(wallDeadline:)`

This script is useful to understand how they behave. Run this from a Swift playground, set your mac to sleep for 30 seconds and check the results. Also, do the same experiment without putting your mac to sleep.

```swift
import Foundation

// Pauses on sleep
let monotonicDispatchSourceTimer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: DispatchQueue.main)
monotonicDispatchSourceTimer.schedule(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 30)
monotonicDispatchSourceTimer.setEventHandler(handler: {
    print("Hello from monotonic makeTimerSource")
})
monotonicDispatchSourceTimer.resume()

// Pauses on sleep
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 30) {
    print("Hello from monotonic DispatchQueue.asyncAfter")
}

// Pauses on sleep
class TimerWrapper: NSObject {
    var timer: Timer?

    func run() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 30, target: self, selector: #selector(fireTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    @objc private func fireTimer(){
        print("Hello from Timer.scheduledTimer")
    }
}

let timerWrapper = TimerWrapper()
timerWrapper.run()

// Doesn't pause on sleep
let timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: DispatchQueue.main)
timer.schedule(wallDeadline: DispatchWallTime.now() + 30)
timer.setEventHandler(handler: {
    print("Hello from DispatchSourceTimer with wall deadline")
})
timer.resume()

// Doesn't pause on sleep
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: DispatchWallTime.now() + 30) {
    print("Hello from DispatchQueue.asyncAfter with wall deadline")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use dispatch_walltime() which uses the wall clock instead of registering for sleep/wake notifications with NSTimer.

Some documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/GCDWorkQueues/GCDWorkQueues.html