# Timer in Mac app not firing when mac is sleeping?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am writing an app that uses an NSTimer:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(Controller.tick), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

I use the timer to kick of work with a seconds precision. The app works great when my mac is not sleeping.

If I leave the app running and put the mac to sleep the timer does not fire anymore.

What is the proper way to have the Timer fire in the app even if the mac is sleeping?

I've looked at [NSTimer continue during sleep mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176980/nstimer-continue-during-sleep-mode) but I could not find the answer in that question on how to let a Timer keep firing even during sleep.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSTimer continue during sleep mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176980/nstimer-continue-during-sleep-mode)

Comment: @holex I did look at that question, but it seemed like that is about taking care of the timer once you wake the mac, not on how to let a timer run while the mac sleeps. Am I missing something here?

Comment: you actually are seeing the right approach over there as the point of the _sleeping-mode_ is to get the non-critical tasks suspended during sleeping to save battery time then get them resumed when the computer has awaken; that is the _sleeping-mode_ about; you may request the system not going to _sleep_ while your app runs but as much as that would be okay with a full screen live-streaming app as much as that would be an annoying behaviour from e.g. a tab-bar app which presents second-line services only. you need to consider your app as a good energy-saver citizen all the times.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying as far as the energy saving side of things. However the purpose of my app is to trigger certain logic regardless of sleep mode. That is the main purpose of the app, so if a user decides to run the app it knows that is what he's asking the app to do. So, then, is there no way to let a Timer fire even if the mac is sleeping?