# How to fire NSTimer when computer is asleep or user is logged out

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstimer

I want to fire the timer after 6 hours. But since my computer is in sleep mode, the timer is not fired after 6 hours. It is being fired 2 minutes after I log in the computer after 6+ hours. Is it possible to fire the timer even if the user is in logout or system sleep mode?

Comment: You can schedule the machine to wake from sleep, power on, go to sleep, or shutdown via [IOPMSchedulePowerEvent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1557076-iopmschedulepowerevent?language=objc). It also depends if it's a MacBook Pro for example or not, because IIRC you can't do this if the lid is closed.

Comment: You can check out [Fermata](https://github.com/iccir/Fermata) - Fermata is a small macOS utility which prevents Lid Close Sleep under certain conditions.

Comment: You can prevent your Mac from sleeping with [NSActivityOptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsactivityoptions?language=objc), etc. Your question is too generic that it's really hard to help. Try with the info I gave you and come back with a code that doesn't work for you with some higher level explanation of what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: If you don't want to prevent the computer from sleeping at all, you could set a timestamp for when the timer was started, and when the computer is woken up, run the scheduled method  immediately. See `didWakeNotification`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1530973-didwakenotification

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSTimer continue during sleep mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176980/nstimer-continue-during-sleep-mode)

Comment: Zrzka @tritonal : instead of prevent mac os to sleep,  is there any other way to achive this?

Comment: Willeke thanks for link,  i have already gone through the this thread.  I want to fire after 6hr means if i set timer at 1pm it should fire on 7pm.  It doesn't matter if mac os sleep in between

Comment: @S.S As said, you could add a listener for `didWakeNotification`, to enforce comparison between the timestamp when `NSTimer` start time to when the computer was woken up. You can also make a `NSTimer` which fires up every second and compares the timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way of doing it. Create an `NSDate` for the upcoming event and set up a timer for comparing current time to that timestamp. This example runs once every second.

```c
- (void) waitFor:(CGFloat)seconds {
    // Set the time to wait
    NSTimeInterval timeInSeconds = seconds; 
    __block NSDate *wait = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeInSeconds];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 repeats:YES block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
        NSDate *time = [NSDate date];
        if ([time timeIntervalSinceDate:wait] > 0) {
            // Do something
        }
    }];
}
```

This way, the process will run immediately after waking up your computer.

**EDIT:** Older threads (such as [NSTimer continue during sleep mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176980/nstimer-continue-during-sleep-mode)) suggest that you would need to reschedule the `NSTimer` after wake, but it doesn't seem to be the case anymore.

Comment: Polling once per second like this is very wasteful of CPU cycles and energy—if you get enough apps that do things like this, your system really starts to suffer. Polling should always be the VERY LAST resort.